# Android Service onBind method receiving stale intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I am instantiating a service as follows:

```
try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SOMEService.class);
        intent.putExtra("key", SOME UUID);
        startService(intent);
        bindService(intent, myServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

inside my service's onBind method, I check whether the supplied key matches the expected key in the service.
This key is refreshed on every transaction.

The issue is, if i close the app and reopen it (forcing the service to rebind), after that the onBind method receives the previous intent with the stale key and not the newer intent with the new key.

Any ideas why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start Service, it will run indefinetely and restart even if Android stops it due to lack of resources. So, when you close app, Service is kept running - you only onbind from it. If you want your Service running only when app is open, stop it when app closes and then start again.

Comment: as of now i have overridden my service's onStartCommand method as to return START_NOT_STICKY flag. That fixed the issue.
Though in the long run, i should figure out a way to correctly stop my service.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try checking the intent in onStartCommand ?, since you are starting the service too.

According to docs:

> Called by the system every time a client explicitly starts the service
>   by calling startService(Intent)
>   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,int,int)

Example:

```
public void onStartCommand (Intent intent, 
            int flags, 
            int startId)
{
     String key = intent.getStringExtra("key");
}
```